# Program crashes on startup with ImageBrush

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, imagebrush

I'm trying to create a very simple window with an ImageBrush background in Visual Studio 2013 as a test for a more complex project. The image shows up in the designer, but the program crashes when I start it up. Here's the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="BackgroundTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Name="grid1">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images\Koala.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the basically empty C# (like I said, just a test):

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace BackgroundTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm positive it has something to do with the ImageBrush, if I delete that part of the XAML the program will run a blank window as expected. Can anyone help me get this running?

Here's the debug output:
A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '7' and line position '14'.

Comment: Maybe it is because of image source? Try "/Images/Koala.jpg"

Comment: I've tried multiple image sources, and adding the image to resources. No luck!

Comment: Have you added folder Images and image to the project? Or they are just somwhere there? Have you tried as source full path like "C:\Images\koala.jpg"?

Comment: The folder "Images" is in the project, it shows up perfectly fine in the designer. I just can't run the program.

Comment: check for errors in `App.xaml` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! I added the image to the program's resources by right-clicking the solution name in the solution explorer -> Properties -> Resources -> Add Resource -> Add Existing file and selecting the picture of the Koala. I changed the code in the XAML to:

```
ImageSource="Resources/Koala.jpg"
```

Taking Eric's advice I clicked on Resources in the Solution explorer, and sure enough the picture was there and I was able to change the build action to Resource. After that it worked perfectly, thanks Eric! I'll check your answer as soon as I have enough reputation. I'm fairly new to stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The build action of your image may be set to Content. Change it to be a Resource instead.

Comment: Still throws the same exception.

Comment: Did it for me though. Had to add it as a resource first. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a backslash in your image source...

Assuming that `Images` is a folder in your solution your image source should be:

```
Source="../Images/Koala.jpg"
```

Or even better:

```
Source="pack://application:,,,/Images/Koala.jpg"
```

Comment: Both options still produce a crash.

Comment: and Images/Koala.jpg is definitely a valid Uri in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Right click on the image and select `properties`
change the `Build Action` to `Resource` and **save** your project.